# using path variable in spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read in a JSON file using Spark SQL. I can do it just fine with a hard coded path, but if I need to change the path in an earlier code chunk I do not want to have to go re-do the path in the SQL. Is there a way to set the path using a variable name and then use that in Spark SQL?

What I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW jsonTable
USING json
OPTIONS (path 'dbfs:/tmp/me/rows.json', multiLine=True);
```

What I want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW jsonTable
USING json
OPTIONS (path mypath, multiLine=True);
```

where `mypath = 'dbfs:/tmp/me/rows.json'`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Views don't take parameters, their definition is static and variables aren't supported, that's neither in options nor view body.

Use [Dataset API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html) for more flexibility.

You can also have a function that takes a parameter and can recreate the view:

```
def updateViewPath(path: String): Unit = {
  spark.sql(s"""
    CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW jsonTable
    USING json
    OPTIONS (path '${path}', multiLine=True);
  """)
}
```